# Missing Closure in Slim

Tags: php, slim

I am trying the Slim framework as the basis for a REST api and have run into the following problem when I try to access it:

```
Missing argument 2 for {closure}()
```

I have googled it and none of the suggestions seemed to apply. This is the entire application:

```
require("vendor/autoload.php");
use Slim\Slim as Slim;
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
include("validate.php");

$app= new Slim();
//
//      Route: GET /test/ID
//
$app->get("/test/:id",function($request,$response,$id) {  <--- ERROR LINE
                $status=accessAllowed("id",$request,$response);
                log_info("Status: $status\n");
        });
$app->run();
```

I'm just learning Slim and I'm assuming this is just a newbie problem. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I'm using version 3 of Slim (newest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are definitely not using slim 3 because

1. Slim 3 no longer has the registerAutoloader(); function, and
2. The class name changed from Slim() to App(), and
3. The proper way to grab a parameter in Slim 3 is {id}, not :id

What you need is the proper callback signature.

```
$app->get("/test/:id",function($id) use ($app) {  <--- ERROR LINE
    $status=accessAllowed("id",$app->request,$app->response);
    print "Status: $status\n";
});
```

Comment: You are correct. I originally downloaded and installed the 3.0 tar.gz file then blindly followed the install instructions at some point and overwrote with 2.6. This would explain the disconnect with the docs I was using. Another issue: Interface 'Interop\\Container\\ContainerInterface' (sorry, i copy and pasted the wrong error)

Comment: PS: I used composer to update using the Beta 3.0 composer.json file. When I try the app, I get the error in my previous comment.

Comment: yeah it sounds like you have Slim 2 and Slim 3 in your project... you should try starting with a fresh project.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did and everything seems to be working. How would I retrieve the ID field from the request.?